# How do retrieve inputstream of two files selected via <input type="file" multiple>

Tags: java, html, groovy

I am selecting two files using html5 tag `

```
<input type="file"  class="labelclass" id="files" style="border: 1px solid #7F9DB9;font-size: 22px
" multiple="multiple">
<input type="button" style="background-image: url(app/images/upload.jpg); width:257px;
    height:58px;border-radius:20px;"   onclick="startRead()">
```

ajax call to send files

```
function startRead()
{
      $.ajax({
        url: 'url?sessionid='+sessionid+'&modelNo='+
        $("#modelno").val()+'&packageName='+$("#packagename").val()+'&version='+$("#version").val()+'',
        data:{"file1":document.getElementById('files').files[0],"file2":document.getElementById('files').files[1]},
        contentType: 'application/exe',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Disposition', document.getElementById('files').files[0].name);
        },
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
        ,error:function(data)
        {alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I want to retrieve inputstream of both files on the server
Server side code is in java or groovy
Please help me to retrieve inputsream using bot happroaches

Answer (score -1):

```
FormFile myFile = configForm.getTheFile();  
InputStream input=myFile.getInputStream();
```

Comment: its not going in form.On click of a button,i am giving ajax call in which i am passing these two files